# How do I access the value of a node in racket?

Tags: racket

I have defined the following node struct:

```
(struct list-node
  (val next) #:mutable #:transparent)
```

When I create a list node `(list-node 0 #f)`, however, I don't know how to access the val of this created node. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The fields of something defined as `(struct <name> (<field-name> ...) ...)` are accessed with `<name>-<field-name>` and (if mutable) set with `set-<name>-<field-name>!`.  There may be options that override these defaults but I don't know them.

So for

```
(struct list-node
  (val next) #:mutable #:transparent)
```

Then `list-node-val` gets the `val` of a `list-node` and `set-list-node-val!` sets it:

```
(let ([n (list-node 3 #f)])
  (set-list-node-val! n (+ 1 (list-node-val n)))
  (set-list-node-next! n (list-node 6 n))
  n)
```

Will return a `list-node` with `val` `6`, and `next` being another `list-node` whose `next` is the original `list-node`.